# Install knitr on own shareLatex server

Tags: knitr, sharelatex

**EDIT**:
According to a [ShareLatex Github](https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex/issues/161) discussion, I should create a `.latexmkrc` file and add the following code (I tried already in the home directory but it didn't work) :

```
my $root_file = $ARGV[-1];

add_cus_dep( 'Rtex', 'tex', 0, 'rtex_to_tex');
sub rtex_to_tex {
    do_knitr("$_[0].Rtex");
}

sub do_knitr {
    my $dirname = dirname $_[0];
    my $basename = basename $_[0];
    system("Rscript -e \"library('knitr'); setwd('$dirname'); knit('$basename')\"");
}

my $rtex_file = $root_file =~ s/\.tex$/.Rtex/r;
unless (-e $root_file) {
    if (-e $rtex_file) {
        do_knitr($rtex_file);
    }
}
```

**EDIT END**

It is possible to use `knitr` on the official ShareLatex server by creating a filed called `*.Rtex`. I have my own ShareLatex server with R and Knitr already installed. Everything works on the command line, but when I create a `*.Rtex` file in my ShareLatex project, it won't compile.

Here is my error code when using this knitr code (`\Sexpr{pi}`) in my Rtex file.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.3.20)  28 MAY 2015 05:52
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
! Emergency stop.
<*> main.tex

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
```

Something very interesting is that I have no `main.tex` file only a `main.Rtex` and I declared this file in my project as main file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back and forth with the developer (James Allen), I finally made it work.

How to config the server to compile *.Rtex files

0) go to your sharelatex server (if it's a docker server use `sudo docker exec -i -t sharelatex bash` to connect)

1) Navigate to `cd /usr/local/share/latexmk/`

2) Create a file called `LatexMk`

3) Post the following code into it

```
my $root_file = $ARGV[-1];

add_cus_dep( 'Rtex', 'tex', 0, 'rtex_to_tex');
sub rtex_to_tex {
    do_knitr("$_[0].Rtex");
}

sub do_knitr {
    my $dirname = dirname $_[0];
    my $basename = basename $_[0];
    system("Rscript -e \"library('knitr'); setwd('$dirname'); knit('$basename')\"");
}

my $rtex_file = $root_file =~ s/\.tex$/.Rtex/r;
unless (-e $root_file) {
    if (-e $rtex_file) {
        do_knitr($rtex_file);
    }
}
```

4) Restart the server (for docker use `sudo docker restart sharelatex`)

Comment: this solution doesn't seem to work in the latest docker install of sharelatex.  I've also amended a comment here: https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex/issues/161

Answer (score 0):

The last time I checked, ShareLaTeX did not support `.Rnw` syntax, which is what you used there `\Sexpr{}`. The syntax for `.Rtex` is `\rinline{}`: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/minimal/

Comment: Thanks for that was not the problem. It can't read Rtex files.